# Programmatical variable change in directive does not run parent scope validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I have a form that comprises a circle in a map. The "circle picker" is implemented as a directive that renders a GoogleMaps map and updates a two-way bound object (with '=' in directive scope) from the parent scope (where the form is).

Code is as follows:

Form HTML

```
<!-- View uses controllerAs:"vm" -->
<circle-location-picker circle="vm.circle"></circle-location-picker>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="vm.circle.center" name="center" required>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="vm.circle.radius" name="radius" required>
```

The circle picker directive (excerpt):

```
angular
  .module('frontend')
  .directive('circleLocationPicker', CircleLocationPicker);

function CircleLocationPicker() {
  return {
     templateUrl: 'app/directives/circleLocationPicker/circleLocationPicker.html',
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
       'circle': '='
     },
     controller: MapController
  };

  function MapController($scope, ...) {
    // Called when the circle is changed in the map
    function circleChanged() {
      var center = $scope.gcircle.getCenter();

      $scope.circle.center.latitude = center.lat();
      $scope.circle.center.longitude = center.lng();
      $scope.circle.radius = $scope.gcircle.getRadius();
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but now I am trying to add a validator on the radius of the circle.

To do it I have added a directive (following [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)) as follows:

```
angular
  .module('frontend')
  .directive('radiusValidator', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.radius = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
          return !viewValue || viewValue > 250;
        };
      }
    }
  })
```

The validator is correctly run on load but whenever I change the circle in the map (and so the value is changed in the directive which updates it in the form controller), it does not run again. Also, the value is not changed in the input field containing the radius.

What is most surprising is that if I add a "debug button" in the form page that onClick just logs the value of `vm.circle` to the console, the value is then updated in the field and the validator is run.

I have tried to add a `$watch(vm.circle, <function that does the log>)` but it does not work...

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Does the click event trigger an angular digest cycle? When is the `circleChanged()` triggered?

Comment: Oh, you are right! I was not triggering a digest cycle. I wrapped the code inside `circleChanged()` in a `$scope.$apply()` and now it works! Thanks!